# How get the last day of a month of a list of dates

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I find different solution for my problem, but i find the correct answer. SO now i have to ask:

I want to find the last day of a month in a list... Every time i get the following Error:

```
AttributeError: 'RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'month'
```

I started like this:

```
temp=pandas.read_csv(filename, delimiter=',')
dates=pandas.to_datetime(temp['Var1'])
```

and i get a list like this:

```
0      2017-01-01 06:00:00
1      2017-01-01 07:00:00
2      2017-01-01 08:00:00
...
Name: Var1, Length: 4053, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

In the list different day are missed, for example some Month can have only 10 days.

I used the following code

```
dates[dates.groupby(dates.index.month).apply(lambda s: np.max(s.index))].tolist()
```

Comment: `dates.groupby([data.index.month]).tail(1)` might help

Comment: What version of pandas your using?

Comment: @Dark and @TD-asker solution didn't work for me when i used a dataframe but this did `df.groupby(df.dates.dt.month).tail(1)`

Comment: @Dillon all the matters is if it worked for the OP :)

Comment: Hello i use Phyton 3...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where other solutions only use the `.month` value, you might miss the differences across different years. Grouping across `.year` and `.month` can avoid this. I'm not sure if this is what you require

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(dates=pd.date_range(start=pd.datetime(2017, 10, 1), periods=20, freq='3W')))
Out[]:
        dates
0  2017-10-01
1  2017-10-22
2  2017-11-12
3  2017-12-03
4  2017-12-24
5  2018-01-14
6  2018-02-04
7  2018-02-25
8  2018-03-18
9  2018-04-08
10 2018-04-29
11 2018-05-20
12 2018-06-10
13 2018-07-01
14 2018-07-22
15 2018-08-12
16 2018-09-02
17 2018-09-23
18 2018-10-14
19 2018-11-04


df.groupby([df.dates.dt.year, df.dates.dt.month]).max()
Out[]:
                 dates
dates dates           
2017  10    2017-10-22
      11    2017-11-12
      12    2017-12-24
2018  1     2018-01-14
      2     2018-02-25
      3     2018-03-18
      4     2018-04-29
      5     2018-05-20
      6     2018-06-10
      7     2018-07-22
      8     2018-08-12
      9     2018-09-23
      10    2018-10-14
      11    2018-11-04

df.groupby([df.dates.dt.year, df.dates.dt.month]).max().values
Out[]:
array([['2017-10-22T00:00:00.000000000'],
       ['2017-11-12T00:00:00.000000000'],
       ['2017-12-24T00:00:00.000000000'],
       ['2018-01-14T00:00:00.000000000'],
       ['2018-02-25T00:00:00.000000000'],
       ['2018-03-18T00:00:00.000000000'],
       ['2018-04-29T00:00:00.000000000'],
       ['2018-05-20T00:00:00.000000000'],
       ['2018-06-10T00:00:00.000000000'],
       ['2018-07-22T00:00:00.000000000'],
       ['2018-08-12T00:00:00.000000000'],
       ['2018-09-23T00:00:00.000000000'],
       ['2018-10-14T00:00:00.000000000'],
       ['2018-11-04T00:00:00.000000000']], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

Comment: If you're going to update your answer with someone else's solution, at least credit them...

Comment: @TD-Asker Apologies if it appeared that way, I didn't refresh. It was my own solution but due to chronology, it can be perceived that I copied the answer. I have added an edit to explain why. (see edit history for reason to why i posted and then removed)

Comment: Hmm... no. I get the Error, that Series have no attribute month. I'm looking for the Index for a boxplot, so i can plot form 1 to x, form x to y and so on. For every month one Boxplot.

Comment: @S.Kociok are you using `.month` or `.dt.month`

Comment: I'm using `.month`, but even with `.dt.month` it doesn't run.

Comment: I have no a realy bad solution: `for xx in range(len(dat64)):
 if dat64[xx].month != 1:
  print(dat64[xx], 'index=',xx)
  break`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['2017-01-01 06:00:00',
                        '2017-01-01 07:00:00',
                        '2017-02-02 08:00:00']})
df['a'] = pd.to_datetime(df['a'])
print(df['a'].groupby(df.a.dt.to_period("M")).apply(lambda x: x.values.max()))
```

Output:

```
a
2017-01   2017-01-01 07:00:00
2017-02   2017-02-02 08:00:00
Freq: M, Name: a, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: I want the last date of my list and no new creation of the date... So if i get for example: 2017-01-31 04:00:00 and 2017-02-01 00:00:00 the programm should give me the index from 2017-01-31 04:00:00 e.g.x=189.